# How to set default date to Persian date in PHP?

Tags: php, datepicker, timezone, jquerydatetimepicker, persian-calendar

How to set default date to Persian date in PHP?

Say, if I `echo` this function `date('Y-m-d')` then it will show **2018-03-05** but I want **1396-12-14** the Persian date

Comment: If it can be done by timezone then please suggest.

Comment: Try this php class : https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4852-PHP-Convert-and-format-dates-of-the-Persian-calendar.html

Comment: This might help you?
 https://www.codeproject.com/articles/28380/persian-calendar-in-php

Answer (score 17):

Please check: http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php

```
<?php

// date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

$now = new DateTime();

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
                "fa_IR@calendar=persian", 
                IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                'Asia/Tehran', 
                IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL, 
                "yyyy-MM-dd");

// It is now: 1396-12-14
echo 'It is now: ' . convert_to_number($formatter->format($now)) ."<br />"; 

// It is now: ۱۳۹۶-۱۲-۱۴
echo 'It is now: ' . $formatter->format($now) ."<br />"; 


// convert to number
function convert_to_number($string) {
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $arabic = ['٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١','٠'];

    $num = range(0, 9);
    $convertedPersianNums = str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($arabic, $num, $convertedPersianNums);

    return $englishNumbersOnly;
}
```

Comment: Thank's to all, but it will not help. What I want is, if I echo date('Y-m-d') then it should return 1396-12-15 instead of 2018-03-06.

Comment: Isn't there any better way to convert numbers to English ones ?

Comment: Use "en_US@calendar=persian", to get English numbering.

Comment: If use `en_US` instead of `fa_IR` then you don't need to use `convert_to_number` function.

Comment: this function just convert date and it doesnt return time!,i want both date and time "Y-m-d h:i"

Answer (score 1):

## Finglish (Persian) date format in php  :

```
<?php

// date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

$now = new DateTime();

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
                "en_US@calendar=persian", 
                IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                'Asia/Tehran', 
                IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL, 
                "yyyy-MMMM-dd");

// It is now: 1401-Bahman-20
echo 'It is now: ' . $formatter->format($now) ."<br />"; 
?>
```

### And If you want to change the date format, see the following link :

https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table