# Convert Gregorian date to solar in WordPress and WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, farsi

I have designed a template for my site and I want all **WordPress** and **WooCommerce** dates in my template to be converted from Gregorian to Solar.

I use the following **shortcode** to display the publication date of my posts:

```
<?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?>
```

But the date it shows me is Gregorian and I want it to be changed to Shamsi.

I know there are many plugins for this, but I want to put some code in my template so that my default template becomes solar date forever.

I need any kind of help that can get me to this feature.

Thank you very much.

---

**Edit:**

I have tried all these codes before but none of them changed the date of WordPress for me.

**I am looking for a code that by placing it in the **`functions.php`** file, will convert all WordPress dates or at least the dates that are displayed in my template to solar.**

[HijriCalendar.class.php](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/43092.html)

[Persian-Calendar](https://github.com/omid/Persian-Calendar/blob/master/persian_calendar.php)

---

**Edit 2:**

I used the moment.js library in my template and also used the **javascript** method but still it didn't work.

[How to change Gregorian date to Persian date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570884/how-to-change-gregorian-date-to-persian-date-in-javascript)

[Convert gregorian date to persian(jalali) date in angular 2 and Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514454/convert-gregorian-date-to-persianjalali-date-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2)

Comment: It might be helpful if you describe any of your efforts thus far. For example, have you made any efforts based on any of the responses in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110844/how-to-set-default-date-to-persian-date-in-php or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377948/convert-date-and-time-to-jalali-in-laravel ?

Comment: Hello. I **edited** my **question**. Also, I apologize for my late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you use get_the_time function to get date then convert it to shamsi date and echo it to display.
code like below work. you can add any other g2p function you want.

```
add_filter('the_time', 'change_date_format');

function change_date_format(){
    //change date language here
    $date = get_the_time('Y/m/d');
    $date = explode('/', $date);
    $farsi_date = g2p($date[0],$date[1],$date[2]);
    return $farsi_date[0].'/'.$farsi_date[1].'/'.$farsi_date[2];
}

function g2p($g_y, $g_m, $g_d)
{
    $g_days_in_month = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    $j_days_in_month = array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29);

    $gy = $g_y-1600;
    $gm = $g_m-1;
    $gd = $g_d-1;

    $g_day_no = 365*$gy+floor(($gy+3)/4)-floor(($gy+99)/100)+floor(($gy+399)/400);

    for ($i=0; $i < $gm; ++$i){
        $g_day_no += $g_days_in_month[$i];
    }

    if ($gm>1 && (($gy%4==0 && $gy%100!=0) || ($gy%400==0))){
        /* leap and after Feb */
        ++$g_day_no;
    }

    $g_day_no += $gd;
    $j_day_no = $g_day_no-79;
    $j_np = floor($j_day_no/12053);
    $j_day_no %= 12053;
    $jy = 979+33*$j_np+4*floor($j_day_no/1461);
    $j_day_no %= 1461;

    if ($j_day_no >= 366) {
        $jy += floor(($j_day_no-1)/365);
        $j_day_no = ($j_day_no-1)%365;
    }
    $j_all_days = $j_day_no+1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 11 && $j_day_no >= $j_days_in_month[$i]; ++$i) {
        $j_day_no -= $j_days_in_month[$i];
    }

    $jm = $i+1;
    $jd = $j_day_no+1;

    return array($jy, $jm, $jd, $j_all_days);
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this and got no answer. Can you provide me with a piece of code so that I can easily convert all WordPress and WooCommerce dates to Jalali (solar)?

Comment: I add code to my answer.

Comment: Your answer for shorts `<?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?>` It worked well. But for the update date of the posts, which is from the shortcode `<?php the_modified_time('Y/m/d'); ?>`; I use which in this case it still shows the update date in Gregorian. Is there a way to display this in Shamsi?

Comment: you can add filter for this too;